# Define a group $G=<x,y:o(x)=4,o(y)=2,o(xy)=3>$. show that $G \cong S_{4}$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, group-isomorphism

I know that $S_{4}=<(1,2,3,4),(1,2)>$, but don't know how to prove the isomorphism

Comment: Hint: $x\mapsto (1,2,3,4)$, $y\mapsto (1,2)$, then show that this is an isomorphism using the fact that $S_4=\langle (1,2,3,4),(1,2)\rangle$.

Comment: @BenS. But you have to prove that there is no larger group satisfying these relations, which requires some work.